# How to write a custom-attribute (directive) in React 16.9?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to use React just for writing a custom-attribute for existing HTML tags?

for example, I want to add `float-label` to an input HTML tag like the following code:

```html
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" float-label="LastName">
```

and call [float-labels.js](https://github.com/pryley/float-labels.js) behind the scene. I want to just extend the regular HTML input tag no more.

Is it possible to use React to extend *current HTML tags* **without** writing a new component/tag (like float-input)?

Comment: Any tags that react doesn't recognise should be transferred to the the page DOM, what happens after that is really up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not have directives, you can do the following:

```js
const CustomInput = ({ floatLabel, ...props }) => (
  <label>
    {floatLabel}
    <input {...props} />
  </label>
);
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomInput type="text" floatLabel="text input label" />
      <CustomInput
        type="checkbox"
        floatLabel="checkbox input label"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write aria-label which will increase your code accessibility

```
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" aria-label="LastName">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define HTML standard attribute if you create a new attribute it will consider as props so you can define aria-label that is a built-in attribute

```
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" aria-label="LastName">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a data attribute instead:

```
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" data-float-label="LastName">
```

This is supported, otherwise hyphen attributes will not be rendered.

Comment: Can you share an example with me? Just for custom-attr & extending an HTML tag. I don't know how to write a simple custom attribute to React at all. No matter with or without dash.

Comment: how are you trying to use it?

Comment: In Angular, We just define a simple custom attribute directive to extend tags. I am looking for this in React. Adding `data-float-label` freely in other components (on inputs) to see the effect.